# How can I apply href and data-toggle to an element except one of its child elements?

Tags: jquery

I want to make a link and data-toggle for all elements inside `tr` except for `.jill`. How can I remove the link and data-toggle only for this specific child?

```js
 $(".jill").removeAttr('data-toggle');
 $(".jill").removeAttr("href");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table style="width:100%">
  <tr href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar">
    <td class="jill">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
     <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The way I do it it is not working

Comment: Well..the href is not applied to the child elements, only the parent element. So the href can't be removed from the children, because the children do not have that attribute.

Comment: Ah ok, so I need to write the href and data-toggle for every single td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment.

The href is not applied to the child elements, only the parent element. So the href can't be removed from the children, because the children do not have that attribute.

So you have a few options, you can either apply the href and data-toggle in each `<td>`, except the ones you want. Or you could set this all with jquery. I'm not sure why you would want to do it in jquery, but if you're dynamically generating these rows you could do this, and use a

```
 .not('.jill')
```

in your selector, then do something like

```
 .attr('href', '#')
```

To set the href.

Answer (score -1):

You should set `href` and `data-toggle` attributes to each `td`, and then you can remove this attributes only for one element.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td href="href-test" data-toggle="test-data-toggle" class="jill" >Jill</td>
    <td href="href-test" data-toggle="test-data-toggle">Smith</td> 
    <td href="href-test" data-toggle="test-data-toggle">50</td>
    <td href="href-test" data-toggle="test-data-toggle">Eve</td>
    <td href="href-test" data-toggle="test-data-toggle">Jackson</td> 
    <td href="href-test" data-toggle="test-data-toggle">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a class="remove">Remove</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".remove").on("click", function() {
    $(".jill").removeAttr('data-toggle');
    $(".jill").removeAttr("href");
});
});
```

Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pf0ybte/2/) for live demo.

Comment: This code is copied directly from the question and does not solve the issue OP was having.

Comment: @rob, we have an question "How can I remove the link and data-toggle only for this specific child?", my post have an answer, you can check jsfiddle to see it at the work.

Comment: Yes it does.. but your example changes the fundamental structure of the HTML elements. If OP wanted to restructure HTML, jquery is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @rob, ok, let me explain more, please check my updated answer above.